# paypal lightbox does not work in IE

Tags: paypal

I am using Paypal lightbox login in my web site. It works fine in chrome and Firefox. But in IE, it doesn't work. The page is loading for long time. Please let me know the solution to resolve it.

Comment: This isn't a programming question

Comment: Ok, But I want to know the reason for the IE issue.